# Number of Model Combinations

Tags: feature-selection, model-selection, combinatorics

I have a model selection combinatorics problem.

My covariate pool consists of six covariates: A1, A2, A3, B, C and D. However, covariates A2 and/or A3 can only be included if A1 is also included. Furthermore, covariate C can either be included in a linear fashion or alternatively as a logarithmic term. The same applies to covariate D.

How many different model combinations are there when performing a best subset selection?

Comment: What exactly does "included in two alternative versions" mean?

Comment: It means that covariate C, for instance, cane either be included in way one (C1) or alternatively in way two (C2) (possibly together with other covariates). It is, however, not possible to use both alternatives in the same model.

Comment: It's unclear what these different "ways" mean.  In particular, where you write "It is ... not possible to use both alternatives in the same model" does that mean neither C1 and D2, nor C2 and D1, can both be included?  To avoid confusion, please edit your post to state the criteria less ambiguously.

Answer (score 2):

Inelegant exhaustive listing---provided I understand the rules:

- 17 ways without `a1`:  `b  c1 c2 d1 d2 c1d1 c1d2 c2d1 c2d2  bc1 bc2 bd1 bd2 bc1d1 bc1d2 bc2d1 bc2d2`
- 4 ways with just `a`'s: `a1 a1a2 a1a3 a1a2a3`
  `
- 68 ways with `a`'s and others

89 altogether, if you must include at least one;  90 if you count 'nothing works'.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I came to the same conclusion.